# Carla install ERROR: carla-0.9.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: numpy, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, shapely, carla

I've just been exploring Carla. I was trying to install Carla for the first time and have been following the documentation. While doing so, I had encountered the following error while trying to install the client-library for Carla 0.9.12+.

> `ERROR: carla-0.9.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Checked out for the dependencies and found that I already have them installed. Tried all basic troubleshooting like upgrading the tools like pip, numpy, shapely etc.,

Out of which the dependency numpy==1.18.4 and Shapely==1.6.4.post2 had some issues while installing. (Something to do with the subprocess and not pip) Which looks something like the below.

**For numpy:**

```
    C:\CARLA_0.9.13\WindowsNoEditor\PythonAPI\carla\dist>pip3 install numpy==1.18.4
    Collecting numpy==1.18.4
      Using cached numpy-1.18.4.zip (5.4 MB)
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
      × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [228 lines of output]
          Running from numpy source directory.
          <string>:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
          C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0g5ldr1p\numpy_04e79321d6dd4eaca29b4b6afa45eb4b\tools\cythonize.py:75: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
            required_version = LooseVersion('0.29.14')
          C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0g5ldr1p\numpy_04e79321d6dd4eaca29b4b6afa45eb4b\tools\cythonize.py:77: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
            if LooseVersion(cython_version) < required_version:
          Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
          Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
          Processing numpy/random\_bit_generator.pyx
          Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
          Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
          Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
          Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
          Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
          Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
          Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
          Cythonizing sources
          blas_opt_info:
          blas_mkl_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          blis_info:
            libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          openblas_info:
            libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
          get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
          customize GnuFCompiler
          Could not locate executable g77
          Could not locate executable f77
          customize IntelVisualFCompiler
          Could not locate executable ifort
          Could not locate executable ifl
          customize AbsoftFCompiler
          Could not locate executable f90
          customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
          Could not locate executable DF
          customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
          Could not locate executable efl
          customize Gnu95FCompiler
          Could not locate executable gfortran
          Could not locate executable f95
          customize G95FCompiler
          Could not locate executable g95
          customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
          customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
          Could not locate executable efort
          Could not locate executable efc
          customize PGroupFlangCompiler
          Could not locate executable flang
          don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
            libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_blas_info:
            libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_blas_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_blas_info:
            libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          accelerate_info:
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0g5ldr1p\numpy_04e79321d6dd4eaca29b4b6afa45eb4b\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
              Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
              Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
              A better performance should be easily gained by switching
              Blas library.
            if self._calc_info(blas):
          blas_info:
            libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0g5ldr1p\numpy_04e79321d6dd4eaca29b4b6afa45eb4b\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
              Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
              Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
              numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
              the BLAS environment variable.
            if self._calc_info(blas):
          blas_src_info:
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0g5ldr1p\numpy_04e79321d6dd4eaca29b4b6afa45eb4b\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
              Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
              Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
              numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
              the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
            if self._calc_info(blas):
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
          lapack_opt_info:
          lapack_mkl_info:
            libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          openblas_lapack_info:
            libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          openblas_clapack_info:
            libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          flame_info:
            libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
            libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
            libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
            libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_info:
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
            libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
            libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
            libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_info:
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
            libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
            libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
            libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          lapack_info:
            libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\prasa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0g5ldr1p\numpy_04e79321d6dd4eaca29b4b6afa45eb4b\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
              Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
              Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
              numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
              the LAPACK environment variable.
            return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
          lapack_src_info:
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0g5ldr1p\numpy_04e79321d6dd4eaca29b4b6afa45eb4b\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
              Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
              Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
              numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
              the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
            return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-sm4b2qbb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:262: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
            warnings.warn(msg)
          running dist_info
          running build_src
          build_src
          building py_modules sources
          creating build
          creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10
          creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy
          creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils
          building library "npymath" sources
          C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-sm4b2qbb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py:539: UserWarning: Fallback spawn triggered. Please update distutils monkeypatch.
            warnings.warn("Fallback spawn triggered. Please update distutils monkeypatch.")
          creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core
          creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src
          creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npymath
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npymath\npy_math_internal.h
            adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npymath' to include_dirs.
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npymath\ieee754.c
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npymath\npy_math_complex.c
          None - nothing done with h_files = ['build\\src.win-amd64-3.10\\numpy\\core\\src\\npymath\\npy_math_internal.h']
          building library "npysort" sources
          creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\common
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\common\npy_sort.h
            adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\common' to include_dirs.
          creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npysort
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npysort\quicksort.c
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npysort\mergesort.c
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npysort\timsort.c
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npysort\heapsort.c
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npysort\radixsort.c
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\common\npy_partition.h
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npysort\selection.c
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\common\npy_binsearch.h
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npysort\binsearch.c
          None - nothing done with h_files = ['build\\src.win-amd64-3.10\\numpy\\core\\src\\common\\npy_sort.h', 'build\\src.win-amd64-3.10\\numpy\\core\\src\\common\\npy_partition.h', 'build\\src.win-amd64-3.10\\numpy\\core\\src\\common\\npy_binsearch.h']
          building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
          creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\multiarray
          conv_template:> build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\multiarray\_multiarray_tests.c
          building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
          BUILD_ARCHITECTURE: 'AMD64', os.name='nt', sys.platform='win32'
          error:
          [end of output]
    
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: metadata-generation-failed
    
    × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
    ╰─> See above for output.
    
    note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
    hint: See above for details.
```

**For Shapely:**

```
    C:\CARLA_0.9.13\WindowsNoEditor\PythonAPI\carla\dist>pip3 install Shapely==1.6.4.post2
    Collecting Shapely==1.6.4.post2
      Using cached Shapely-1.6.4.post2.tar.gz (225 kB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
      × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [10 lines of output]
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
            File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
            File "C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-si8vrlv_\shapely_b1efbac9fb88492bb6bb5854189a034f\setup.py", line 80, in <module>
              from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
            File "C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-si8vrlv_\shapely_b1efbac9fb88492bb6bb5854189a034f\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
              lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
            File "C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
              self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
          FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'geos_c.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
          [end of output]
    
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: metadata-generation-failed
    
    × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
    ╰─> See above for output.
    
    note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
    hint: See above for details.
```

Please Help me out here! TIA!

Answer (score 1):

If carla cannot be installed, it is recommended to use the whl installation solution:

1. Download the wheel from here: https://pypi.org/project/carla/#files
2. Unzip and download as shown in Figure ① below
3. Move to `${HOME}$/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` as shown below ②
4. Finally, when grep carla below, as shown in figure ③ below

Checkin [this issue](https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/issues/5482#issuecomment-1434462245)

Reference: https://imtiazulhassan.medium.com/solving-the-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-carla-error-d18cfb442f67